# Nuget Command Line Parser Library 1.9.74 library exiting with code 0x01

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, command-line

I have a C# command line program that unexpectedly ends with the message: `The program '[2072] csgrep.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1)`.

The shortened code is as follow:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var parser = new CommandLine.Parser(s =>
        {
            s.CaseSensitive = true;
        });

        // the application unexpectedly stops when calling this method.
        var isValid = parser.ParseArgumentsStrict(args, options);

        if (isValid)
        {
            ... run my application here
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input error.");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

`CommandLine.Parser` and `ParseArgumentsStrict` are from the nuget package " Command Line Parser Library1.9.74 " (https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommandLineParser19/)

When I "step into" with the debugger, the application stops at `var isValid = parser.ParseArgumentsStrict(args, options);`

My problem is that I do not really know how to troubleshoot the problem. How can I find out where the problem is?

Comment: From documentation, ParseArgumentsStrict : *success or quit*. So your answer is it fails so it quits. https://github.com/gsscoder/commandline/wiki/Best-Practices

Comment: what are the options and args are you passing. Can you please share those values , Otherwise is not possible to tell why the grep is failing.

Comment: Rafalon: thanks that put me on the right track. Silly me! It never occured to me to inspect the source code of the nuget package. From the sources it is clear that if no `OnFail` action is passed to the `ParseArgumentsStrict` method then it will exit immediately. I fixed it by providing an `OnFail` parameter to the method and then it behaved as expected.

Comment: loneshark99: it did not really matter, wether I called it with no parameters or any parameters, it would still fail.

Comment: In the meanwhile I figured that `var parser = new CommandLine.Parser(s =>
                {
                    s.CaseSensitive = true;
                });` is probably causing the problem. Using the default static parser that the library provides (`var parser = CommandLine.Parser.Default;`) works fine, although it is case insensitive, which is not what I wanted.

Comment: It turns out that if I provide a `TextWriter` instance for the `helpWriter` property, then I can print out the help on parse failure on my own `OnFail' method. So in conclusion I'd have to say that Rafalon was spot on with his suggestion on how to find the cause of the program exiting with code 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code can be changed as follow not to exit unexpectedly with code 1:

```
static void OnCommandLineParseFail()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Command line parse failure");

    Console.WriteLine("Help: " + parser.Settings.HelpWriter.ToString());
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        StringWriter t = new StringWriter();

        var parser = new CommandLine.Parser(s =>
        {
            s.CaseSensitive = true;
            s.HelpWriter = t;
            s.IgnoreUnknownArguments = false;
        });

        var isValid = parser.ParseArgumentsStrict(args, options, OnCommandLineParseFail);

        if (isValid)
        {
            ... run my application here
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input error.");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```